# _placesClient lookUpPlaceID neither executing nor showing any error

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I am using a Place Id to get details of a place i am following this 
https://developers.google.com/places/ios/place-details

```
NSString * placeID ;//= place.placesId;
placeID=place.placesId;

[_placesClient lookUpPlaceID:place.placesId callback:^(GMSPlace *place,     NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Place Details error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }

    if (place != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
        NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
        NSLog(@"Place placeID %@", place.placeID);
        NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No place details for %@", placeID);
    }
}];
```

But the code is not executing and jumping of the statement

```
[_placesClient lookUpPlaceID:place.placesId callback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
    ...
}];
```

Any clues ,i have also initialised _place client as follows

```
_placesClient = [[GMSPlacesClient alloc] init];
```

Comment: What's the value of place.placesId?  Make sure it's not nil.

Comment: Thanks i got it working ...it actually takes time to callback..

Comment: From the .h:

Main interface to the Places SDK. Used for searching and getting details about places. This class should be accessed through the
[GMSPlacesClient sharedClient] method.

GMSPlacesClient methods should only be called from the main thread. Calling these methods from another thread will result in an exception or undefined behavior. Unless otherwise specified, all callbacks will be invoked on the main thread.